# Extract XML via Oracle Table

Tags: xml

I'm looking to extract the value of 04:30 DAILY from the below XML. Data type is CLOB and in table esp_event_df in column DEFINITION. Any help would be much appreicated. I have tried looking at other posts and trying things out but can't seem to get the results I need.

```
<even:eventenum xmlns:even="http://dto.wa.ca.com/event">
<even:eventsch itu="no">
    <even:description>
        <even:name>PROD.IOPS_HOUSEKEEPING_CAWAPROD</even:name>
        <even:executionuser>SCHEDMASTER</even:executionuser>
        <even:holdcount>0</even:holdcount>
        <even:suspendcount>0</even:suspendcount>
    </even:description>
    <even:schedule>
        <even:scheduleelement original="04:30 DAILY" scheduledTriggerTime="2020-08-01_04:30:00.000"> EVERY 1 DAY 04:30:00.000 STARTING 2020/08/02 04:30:00.000 EDT</even:scheduleelement>
        <even:noscheduleelement original="Jul 31, 2020 4:30AM once"/>
        <even:inactiveonly>true</even:inactiveonly>
    </even:schedule>
    <even:action>
        <even:runApplication>IOPS_HOUSEKEEPING_CAWAPROD</even:runApplication>
    </even:action>
    <even:priority>5</even:priority>
    <even:comment>Event created on 6/8/19 10:39 AM for the IOPS_HOUSEKEEPING_CAWAPROD application.</even:comment>
</even:eventsch>
```

</even:eventenum>

Comment: try with this xpath:  //even:scheduleelement/@original

Comment: Thank you but how to I execute that query to get the data? Silly quetion I know but I don't have any experience with xpaths. Failed to mention it is Oralce if that matters. I am using Toad to issue my SQL queries. What would the full command look like to get the data?